# Simply connected codomain => bounded derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U,V\subseteq \mathbf{C}$ be open sets where $V$ is simply
>   connected and $V\neq \mathbf{C}$. Prove that for any $c\in U$ there is
>   a constant $M<\infty$ so that $|f'(c)|\leq M$ for all analytic maps
>   $f:U\to V$.

I have no idea how to start this one. I can't think of a way to use the fact that the codomain is simply connected.

EDIT: As Daniel Fischer pointed out the claim is false.

Comment: Simply connected and not the entire plane: think unit disk. Have you an idea how to prove it if $V = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$?

Comment: Ah, I see the reason for the simple connectedness now. It suffices to do the unit disk and then get the full result by the Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: And the unit disk is easy, since $f$ is bounded and we can just use the Cauchy estimate. Thanks!

Comment: @dmtr If you want, you can now post your own answer to the question :)

Comment: I intend to when I finish it, but I'm afraid I spoke too soon.

If $f:U\to V$ and $g:V\to D$ is the conformal map, then
$|(g\circ f)'(z_0)|\leq M$ implies that $|g'(f(z_0))||f'(z_0)|\leq M$,
but I see no reason that $g'(f(z_0))$ can't get arbitrarily small.

Comment: Actually, the assertion is false, which explains why you have problems proving it. Let for example $U = V = \mathbb{H}$ the upper half-plane. Consider $f_r(z) = r\cdot z$ for $r > 0$. We get boundedness if we assume $V$ bounded (then simple connectedness plays no role of course) from the Cauchy estimates. Or we get boundedness if we restrict our attention to the functions satisfying $f(u_0) = v_0$ for some fixed $u_0\in U$ and $v_0\in V$. ($f(u_0) \in K$ for some compact $K\subset V$ will do, we don't need $K$ to be a singleton.)